# Why do you have to use fetch for Rails params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters

In the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-fetch), they have:

```
params = ActionController::Parameters.new(person: { name: "Francesco" })
```

and then use `params.fetch(:person)` to get person, but can't you just do `params[:person]`? to get the same data?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suppose it depends on the behavior you desire.

```
params = ActionController::Parameters.new
params.fetch(:person)
```

Will raise an error. As reflected in the docs, you can specify further behavior with `fetch`, if you so desire.

```
params = ActionController::Parameters.new
params[:person]
```

Will return `nil`.

Comment: It should be added that you can `params.fetch(:person, "")` to avoid the error. `fetch` is better IMO, since you can decide the value to fall back to if the one you're trying to get doesn't exist.

Comment: @Iceman great add! I'm going to consider moving in this direction since it seems like a really good idea to be explicit about the behavior one wants when a value is missing.

Answer (score 3):

> Why do you have to use fetch for Rails params?

You don't.

You're looking at the [documentation for `fetch` method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-fetch). Naturally, it uses `fetch` everywhere. There's also [`[]` method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-5B-5D):

```
params = ActionController::Parameters.new(person: { name: "Francesco" })
params[:person] # => <ActionController::Parameters {"name"=>"Francesco"} permitted: false>
params[:none]   # => nil
```

Comment: ok so is there a difference between the `[]` and `fetch` method? according to @jvillian, seems like the latter can throw an error whereas the former will silently return nil?

Comment: `fetch` doesn't throw an error if you provide a second parameter which acts as a default value @stackjlei